# Create Duplicates of Sheets and name them according to a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

massive JS noob here, trying to adapt this script to create duplicates of a named sheet (i'll change this to active sheet after figuring out how to add a UI/Menu) and loop through a range A2:A which will hold variables which I want the sheets to be named.

This script *sort* of works, in the sense it does loop through and create the duplicate sheets for me. I can't figure out why there is an error showing at line 22. In addition the script also duplicates the "Template sheet" which is not a wanted behavior. Can anyone edify me as to why this is happening? Cheers guys.

```
   function createEmployeeSheets() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var employeeID = ss.getSheetByName("EmployeeRef")

   // Get the range of cells that store employee data.
  var employeeDataRange = employeeID.getRange("A2:A")

  var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();

  var template = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

  for (var i=0; i < employeeObjects.length; i++) {

     // Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i]);

      // Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
      // log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.
        if (sheet) {
           Logger.log("Sheet " + employeeObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {
           template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
           }
        }
  return;
}
```

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

Apologies the error message I get is :

```
The sheet name cannot be empty. (line 32, file "Code"
```

which is this line :

```
template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
```

additionally, after the script has finished itearating on A2:2 on the EmployeeRef sheet it creates another duplicate sheet called Copy of Template. What I wanted was to duplicate sheets as many times as there are names in the range A2:A.

so,

```
Mo
Jon
Adelle
```

would only generate three sheets, but i'm getting 3 + 1 with the +1 being called a copy of the template sheet.

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase it!

Comment: done, hopefully this is clear enough for you my man.

Comment: What's not to understand about the error? You are pulling the sheet name from `employeeObjects[i]`, and the error says the sheet name is empty, which means the ith index of `employeeObjects` has either an undefined or "" value. Because Apps Script can't set a name for that copy of the template, it keeps the default name. Your code never validates the names it attempts to use. Please ensure you debug your scripts as a part of [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hey buddy, figured out my issue! I was referencing A2:A which was looping through all cells hence the error at line22. Once I changed my cell ref from A2:A5 for this example. I guess using a named range would be better as it wouldn't need to be edited each time a row was added?

Comment: How about modifying to ``var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues().filter(String).map(function(e){return e[0]})``? ``filter(String)`` removes the empty values. ``map(function(e){return e[0]})`` converts 2 dimensional array to 1 dimensional array. By this, you can use "A2:A" for ``var employeeDataRange = employeeID.getRange("A2:A")``. In the case of this modification, you can add rows freely without modifying script.

Comment: you my man are a genius, can you post that as an answer? ill green tick!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually, I had already posted an answer. But because I noticed that the answer has already been in comment, I had deleted it. Now I undelete it. Could you please confirm it? If this answer useful for you, I'm glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? I understand about your issue as follows.

1. Error of `The sheet name cannot be empty. (line 32, file "Code"`.
2. Sheet of `Copy of Template` is created.

I think that the reasons of your issues are as follows.

### Reasonof the issues

#### 1. Error of `The sheet name cannot be empty. (line 32, file "Code"`

This error is due to `null` from the empty value of the cell.

- When the values are retrieved from "A2:A", the values of cells from A2 to last row of the sheet are retrieved. When the last row of the sheet is larger than the row of data range, it is over the data range.

  - So `employeeObjects` includes the empty rows.
- In your script, the exist of sheet is judged using `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i]);` and `if (sheet) {}`.

  - When `employeeObjects[i]` is empty, namely, it's `[""]`, `sheet` is `null`. It's `false` at "if".

As the result, such error occurs by trying to modify the sheet name using the empty value.

#### 2. Sheet of `Copy of Template` is created.

This error is due to that `employeeObjects[i]` is `""`.

- From above reason, it was found that `employeeObjects` includes the empty values like `""`.
- Under this situation, when `template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);` is run, I think that the following flow occurs.

  1. Copy `template` to `ss`. In this case, `ss` is the active Spreadsheet.
  2. Modify the sheet name by `setName(employeeObjects[i])`. At that time, the error occurs because of the empty value.

     - When `template` was copied, the sheet name is `Copy of Template`. And the sheet name is NOT modified because of the error.

As the result, the sheet of `Copy of Template` is created.

I think that in order to avoid the error, there are several ways. So please think of this modification as one of them.

### Modification

#### Modification points :

- Remove empty values from `employeeObjects`.
- Retrieve values from 2 dimensional array. `employeeObjects` is 2 dimensional array.

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();
```

To :

```
var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues().filter(String).map(function(e){return e[0]});
```

- `filter(String)` removes the empty values.
- `map(function(e){return e[0]})` converts 2 dimensional array to 1 dimensional array.

  - I used this for using the original script in "for loop".

#### References :

- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Extremely informative, hopefully others will find this of use. the Filter and map functions worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @Datanovice I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.